# Maximum call stack size exceeded in merge sort

Tags: javascript, algorithm, mergesort

I'm studying about merge sort and implement it in JavaScript, but it returned an error:

> function mergeSort(input) {
>
> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Here is my code:

```
var array = [2,4,6,7,1,3,5,10,9,8];

// using merge sort: (best sort => O (n log n))
function mergeSort (array) {
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length/2; i++) {
    array1.push(array[i]);
}

for (let i = array.length/2; i < array.length; i++) {
    array2.push(array[i]);
}

array1 = mergeSort(array1);
array2 = mergeSort(array2);

return merge(array1, array2);
}

function merge(a, b) {
let c = [];

while(a.length > 0 && b.length > 0) {
    if (a[0] > b[0]) {
        c.push(b[0]);
        b.splice(0, 1);
    } else {
        c.push(a[0]);
        a.splice(0, 1);
    }
}

while (a.length > 0) {
    c.push(a[0]);
    a.splice(0, 1);
}

while (b.length > 0) {
    c.push(b[0]);
    b.splice(0, 1);
}

return c;
}

console.log(mergeSort(array));
```

I guess the error is in `mergeSort` function. I'm implementing it with a recursion.

Comment: mergeSort takes smt but smt isnt used, and what is array?

Comment: Hello, @Keitaro. Have you been able to solve your issue?

Comment: @KidBinary oh, I'm too busy these days due to project so I forgot to read and accept ur answer. Yes, the problem is related to the  condition to stop the recursion. :)

Comment: @Keitaro nice, glad to help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That particular reason is related to infinite recursion inside the `mergeSort` function. You're calling it deeper and deeper without any condition to stop. So the `mergeSort` should be re-written like this:

```
function mergeSort(input) {
  // Here is your recursion stop condition
  if (input.length === 1) return input;

  const median = Math.floor(input.length / 2);

  // Limit arrays should get sliced with each iteration
  const limitA = input.slice(0, median);
  const limitB = input.slice(median);

  return merge(
    mergeSort(limitA), mergeSort(limitB)
  );
};
```