# Merge Sort question: Maximum call stack exceeded, avoided infinite recursion

Tags: javascript, mergesort, callstack

Unable to get a terminal output because of error:
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Tried to look at similar questions on stackoverflow,
like this [Maximum call stack size exceeded in merge sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46973257/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-in-merge-sort) and added conditionals to possibly stop infinite recursion.

Still couldn't fix the problem. Hopefully looking for an answer.

```
const unsortedArray = [1, 10, 5, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 9];
const sortedArray = Array(unsortedArray.length);

function sort(unsortedArray, start, middle, end) {

    let i= start;
    let j= middle;
    let k= start;

    while(i < middle && j <= end) {

        if(unsortedArray[i]<=unsortedArray[j]) {
            sortedArray[k] = unsortedArray[i];
            i++
        } else {
            sortedArray[k] = unsortedArray[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++
    }

    if (i >= middle) {
        while(j<= end) {
            sortedArray[k] = unsortedArray[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    } else if (j >= end) {
        while (i <= middle) {
            sortedArray[k] = unsortedArray[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
    }
}

function splitMerge(unsortedArray, start, end) {
    if(end>start) {
        middle = Math.floor((start + end)/2);
        splitMerge(unsortedArray, start, middle);
        splitMerge(unsortedArray, middle, end);
        sort(unsortedArray, start , middle, end);
    }
    return sortedArray;
}

const showResult = splitMerge(unsortedArray, 0, unsortedArray.length-1);
console.log(showResult);
```

Comment: pls explain what do you want to achieve here? so many iterations are not a good approach.

Comment: Was trying to mimic merge sort algorithm I learned in JS.
Does the code have too many iteration? Isn't this the usual approach?

Comment: nop, it's not a usual approach, always avoid too many iterations and conditions inside your logic and try to make it as simple and straightforward as you can.